# Getting CKEditor plugin stylesheetparser to work - editor.filter is undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm trying to get stylesheetparser to work but am getting the error "editor.filter is undefined".

Here is my config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'colors' },          
        { name: 'document',       groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },      
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';

    config.contentsCss = 'editor_new.css';

    // Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
    // need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = '';
};
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. See [stylesheetparser sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/stylesheetparser/stylesheetparser.html) - it works fine. Although, this may be caused by configuration of your CKEditor package. Which plugins have you included?

Comment: Just the defaults I think. I temporarily fixed it by putting my styles in the default stylesheet.

Comment: The default packages (neither standard nor full) does not contain the stylsheet parser plugin. Please attach `build-config.js` file from main CKEditor directory.